# Comparing Hours in C/C++ in 24hours format

Tags: c++, c

How do I determine if there is a difference of 4 hours between two times, given in a 24-hours format?

I've tried this:

```
time_t  timeP;
time(&timeP);
//....
time_t  nowP;
time(&nowP);

if((nowP - timeP) % 4 == 0){
    //...
}
```

Any better idea, please?

Comment: And what didn't work?

Comment: Hints: Do you think `time_t` represents hours or some other unit of time? What do you think  the `%` operator does?

Comment: You can also check if `(nowP & 3) == (timeP & 3)`... might be a little faster, depending on you CPU architecture, but I doubt that this is really what you're trying to gain here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((nowP - timeP) % 4 == 0)
```

This code takes the time difference in seconds modulo 4 which probably doesn't have much value to you.

```
if ((nowP - timeP) >= 60*60*4)
```

This would tell you that 4 hours have elapsed between the two time points. You shouldn't use `==` for comparing times to avoid skipping the time you want to check (e.g. The computer is slow and lags, the system time is synced and skips a second, ...).